# iPhone simulator crashes because of GDP error, also has warning:

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator

warning: 'RootViewController' may not respond to '-peformSelector:withObject:afterDelay:'

crash in debugger console:

```
    {[Session started at  
2011-04-30 21:57:58 +0800.] 
2011-04-30 21:57:59.414 Gravity Man[57133:207] -[RootViewController peformSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e0d740 
2011-04-30 21:57:59.417 Gravity Man[57133:207] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController peformSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e0d740' * 
Call stack at first throw: ( 
    0 CoreFoundation 0x00f0cbe9     exceptionPreprocess + 185 
    1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x010615c2    objc_exception_throw + 47 
    2 CoreFoundation 0x00f0e6fb     -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187 
    3 CoreFoundation 0x00e7e366     __forwarding + 966 
    4 CoreFoundation 0x00e7df22     _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50 
    5 Gravity Man 0x00002c8d    -[RootViewController viewWillAppear:] + 471 
    6 UIKit 0x00374c9a      -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 858 
    7 UIKit 0x0036f606      -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266 
    8 UIKit 0x00487e01      -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 226 
    9 QuartzCore 0x00cab451     -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181 
    10 QuartzCore 0x00cab17c    CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220 
    11 QuartzCore 0x00ca437c    _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310 
    12 QuartzCore 0x00ca40d0    _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292 
    13 UIKit 0x002bb19f         -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 39 
    14 UIKit 0x002bb659         -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 690 
    15 UIKit 0x002c5db2         -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533 
    16 UIKit 0x002be202         -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71 
    17 UIKit 0x002c3732         _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576 
    18 GraphicsServices         0x01842a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550 
    19 CoreFoundation 0x00eee064    CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 52 
    20 CoreFoundation 0x00e4e6f7    __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215 
    21 CoreFoundation 0x00e4b983    __CFRunLoopRun + 979 
    22 CoreFoundation 0x00e4b240    CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208 
    23 CoreFoundation 0x00e4b161    CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97 
    24 UIKit 0x002bafa8         -[UIApplication _run] + 636 25 UIKit 0x002c742e UIApplicationMain + 1160 26 Gravity Man 0x0000282a main + 84 
    27 Gravity Man 0x000027cd   start + 53 
) terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

}
```

.h:

```
{

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel* Label1;
IBOutlet UILabel* Label2;
IBOutlet UILabel* Label3;
IBOutlet UIImageView* Image1;
IBOutlet UIImageView* Image2;
IBOutlet UIImageView* Image3;
IBOutlet UIButton* newGameButton;
IBOutlet UIButton* facebookButton;
IBOutlet UIButton* settingsButton;

CAKeyframeAnimation* popAnimation;
}

-(IBAction)newGame:(id)sender;

@end

}
```

.m:

```
@implementation RootViewController

-(IBAction) newGame:(id)sender { GameScreen* pong = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameScreen" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:pong animated:NO];
} -(void)popView:(UIView*)view { [view setHidden:NO]; [[view layer] addAnimation:popAnimation forKey:@"transform.scale"]; } - (void)viewDidLoad {

    popAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    popAnimation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
    popAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.01], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
    [popAnimation retain];

    [super viewDidLoad];



}   
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[popAnimation setDuration:0.9];
[Label1 setHidden:YES]; [Label2 setHidden:YES]; [Label3 setHidden:YES]; [newGameButton setHidden:YES]; [facebookButton setHidden:YES]; [settingsButton setHidden:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:Label1 afterDelay:0.9]; [self performSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:Label2 afterDelay:0.95]; [self performSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:Label3 afterDelay:1];
    //"WARNING SHOWS UP AMONG THESE LINES"// 
[self performSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:newGameButton afterDelay:0.9]; 
[self peformSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:settingsButton afterDelay:0.95]; 
[self performSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:facebookButton afterDelay:1];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }


@end

}
```

Thank you and please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
[self peformSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:settingsButton afterDelay:0.95];`
       ^^
```

into

```
[self performSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:settingsButton afterDelay:0.95];`
       ^^^
```

IE add **r** between **pe** and **formSelector**

Answer (score 0):

copy that to your .h file:

```
-(void)popView:(UIView*)view;
```

that should do the trick.